# "Unable to get local issuer certificate" after changing the certificate External CA

Tags: git, ssl

After changing certificate from one to another (both - the old and the new one were from external trusted CA's) we are experiencing issues with git telling us:

SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I am aware that such things can happen when having a self-signed corporate certificate, but what in case we got a certificate from an external trusted CA?

This CA is from home.pl, a well known provider here in Poland.

Comment: I would guess that you are failing to bundle the intermediate certificate(s) with the server certificate. Every real CA has one or more intermediate certificates that have to be bundled along with the server certificate. Basically, the server has to send all the certificates except the root certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is correct. home.pl certificate file does not contain the intermediate CA certs. You will have to donwlnaod it separately and add to the cert file on the server. Simply coy paste them into the file. Please keep in mind that the itnermediate CA cert